# Vuetify v-date-picker doesnt show up when changing to range prop

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using this code on my project, it's a text-field that when I click on it pops a dialog which shows a calendar.

This works fine, however when I insert the range prop on the v-date-picker, the calendar doesn't show up anymore, only the dialog background. It is working fine on this codepen you can see below:

See the Pen 
[Vuetify Example Pen](https://codepen.io/izzyDL/pen/QWOXrzM) by Simão ([@izzyDL](https://codepen.io/izzyDL))
on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        cols="11"
        sm="5"
      >
        <v-dialog
          ref="dialog"
          v-model="modal"
          :return-value.sync="date"
          persistent
          width="290px"
        >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="date"
              label="Picker in dialog"
              prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
              readonly
              v-bind="attrs"
              v-on="on"
            ></v-text-field>
          </template>
          <v-date-picker
            v-model="date"
            scrollable
            range
          >
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn
              text
              color="primary"
              @click="modal = false"
            >
              Cancel
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn
              text
              color="primary"
              @click="$refs.dialog.save(date)"
            >
              OK
            </v-btn>
          </v-date-picker>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below is using your code and the picker shows up just fine. Am I missing something in your question?

One thing I should point out is that when using **range** prop date picker expects its model to be an array of length 2 or empty. In your code, the `date` prop is a `string`. It doesn't affect the calendar rendering though.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU41Y.png)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    date: ['2019-09-10', '2019-09-20'],
    menu: false,
    modal: false,
  }),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="11" sm="5">
        <v-dialog ref="dialog" v-model="modal" :return-value.sync="date" persistent width="290px">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="date"
              label="Picker in dialog"
              prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
              readonly
              v-bind="attrs"
              v-on="on"
            ></v-text-field>
          </template>
          <v-date-picker v-model="date" scrollable range>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn text color="primary" @click="modal = false">
              Cancel
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs.dialog.save(date)">
              OK
            </v-btn>
          </v-date-picker>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```